# JS Functions with PHP mysqli_fetch_assoc echo

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a PHP echo where I display the results of a select query with mysqli_fetch_assoc and echo * only a section of the echo is below *. But I want the togglepage function to run on the click of one of the svg with the id of toggle. However because I'm echoing the array of results, only the first echo of result works, the rest don't because the ids are all the same. How do I do it so that the function works with every result echo. Thanks

HTML/PHP :

```
echo'
    <svg id="toggle" onclick="togglepage()" class="hover-box-menu2 toggle-page" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M7.5 15L12.5 10L7.5 5" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
    </svg>
    ';
```

JS :

```
function togglepage() {
    if (document.getElementById("toggle").style.transform == "rotate(0deg)" || document.getElementById("toggle").style.transform == "") {
        document.getElementById("toggle").style.transform = "rotate(90deg)";
    }
    else if (document.getElementById("toggle").style.transform == "rotate(90deg)") {
        document.getElementById("toggle").style.transform = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Are your svg elements created dynamically by PHP? If so, you need to change the id selector to a class selector then use the `this` key word on your event click to tell JS which element is being clicked on.

Comment: Specifically, `onclick="togglepage(this)"`. Then use the function parameter instead of `document.getElementById("toggle")`

Comment: ^ this. take out that `id`. just pass `this` in `togglepage(this)`

Comment: @Kevin what would it be? document.this.style etc?

Comment: then just simply add an argument in your function `function togglepage(toggle)`, then use `toggle` all through out instead of getelementbyid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a different approach:

First of all we write some JS that does the following

1. Select all SVG elements on the page
2. Loop through these elements adding a 'click' event listener
3. Make the click event toggle a `rotate` class

Then we create a css class `.rotate` and add the transform property to it.

Now when you click the SVGs it will rotate between 90deg and 0deg.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.rotateable').forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', () => {
    el.classList.toggle('rotate')
  })
})
```

```css
.rotate {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  /* more styles here */
}
```

```html
<svg class="rotateable hover-box-menu2" width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="black" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M7.5 15L12.5 10L7.5 5" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
</svg>
<svg class="rotateable hover-box-menu2" width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="black" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M7.5 15L12.5 10L7.5 5" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
</svg>
<svg class="rotateable hover-box-menu2" width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="black" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M7.5 15L12.5 10L7.5 5" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: I dont want to do it for all the svg elements on the page,noly a select few. That's why I used the onclick event. Others are suggesting that I use this as the parameter. Thanks for the answer though

Comment: I've updated my answer, now we add a ".rotateable" class to the elements we want to be able to rotate and select only those elements.

Comment: If I wanted to change the styling more, do I just create more classes and reference them with el.classList.toggle?

Comment: You can add more styles into the .rotate class and they will be applied when the rotate class is applied. I've edited my answer with "more styles here".

Comment: Ah yes, sorry I don't know how I didn't think of that, maybe because it was called rotate lol. Thanks, this answer has been very helpful